# How to improve performance on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging

I have a program written with Codeigniter which turns out to be very slow when logging out.

When I debug the program, I realize that there is a step that lasts for 10 s

> Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver

here is the complete debug

```
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:05 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:05 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-09-20 12:56:05 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:05 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:05 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:05 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:05 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Language Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Loader Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Helper loaded: string_helper
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Helper loaded: language_helper
DEBUG - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Session: "sess_save_path" is empty; using "session.save_path" value from php.ini.
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:06 --> Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver.
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:16 --> Language file loaded: language/french/messages_lang.php
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:16 --> File loaded: C:\wamp\www\SESAME\application\views\template/header.php
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:16 --> File loaded: C:\wamp\www\SESAME\application\views\connect_user.php
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:16 --> File loaded: C:\wamp\www\SESAME\application\views\template/footer.php
INFO - 2017-09-20 12:56:16 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2017-09-20 12:56:16 --> Total execution time: 10.8679
```

Can you help me find the cause of this low performance?

Comment: So this "delay" only happens on logout and on no other page? What I did notice is that the log is reporting that $config['sess_save_path'] is not being set... What are you config file for the sessions settings and what is the code associated with the logout?

Comment: CI is one of the fastest Frameworks out there - i'm not sure if this waiting time is happening during the session loading or somewhere else - so you've  to provide the code where you load those drivers (session driver and language file)

Comment: You can set it another way or try with absolute path

Comment: Does your website use frequent AJAX requests?

Comment: @Narf can you please post some suggestion regarding improving performance because Codeigniter needs a lot to improve. I have posted one on GitHub also which you guys aren't solved yet.

Comment: @Narf what about [this](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5231) have any solution???

Comment: @ankitsuthar What has that got to do with this question?

Comment: fewer bugs mean more improved framework sir. that's what I am saying. @Narf

Comment: The sessions class makes the log entry at the end of Session initialization. In other words, the time logged shows when session load is done. The delay is either 1) What happens after Session is loaded and the start of the  language file load call, or 2) The language file is taking a long time to load. Please show the code in the controller/method that is executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think  "Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver." taking time.

Files Driver:
The ‘files’ driver uses your file system for storing session data.

AS per [Codeigniter Session](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html) documentation you can change storage engine session in database or other places like files, redis, memcached.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Also, you can set absolute path :

To be more specific, it doesn’t support PHP’s directory level and mode formats used in session.save_path, and it has most of the options hard-coded for safety. Instead, only absolute paths are supported for $config['sess_save_path'].

Comment: The session class is not the problem. Literally the very last thing that the Session class constructor does is make the log entry "Session: Class initialized using...". It is the language that is taking a along time to load.

Comment: I just tried this method and it does not really solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause to my problem.

In fact, it is a rather heavy class that my controller was loading every time (`registered_user` - when I comment it, the program becomes much faster - )

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_inscription');
    $this->load->model('user_connexion');
    $this->load->model('mouchard');
    $this->load->model('synchronisation');
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('language');
    $this->load->library('session');
    //$this->load->library('registered_user');
    $this->load->library('sendsms');
}
```

and here is the class. It connects to an oracle database. I don't know why it takes so much time to instanciate.

```
class Registered_user {

    private $query;
    private $connexion;

    public function __construct($host, $port, $serviceName, $user, $passwd) {
        $baseLink = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = ' . $host . ')(Port = ' . $port . '))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ' . $serviceName . ')))';
        $this->connexion = oci_connect($user, $passwd, $baseLink);
    }

    public function getConnexion() {
        return $this->connexion;
    }

    public function setQuery($query) {
        /*set the query*/
    }

    public function getInfos() {

        $stid = oci_parse($this->connexion, $this->query);
        oci_execute($stid);

        $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);

        return $row;
    }

}
```